# Uncaught ReferenceError in javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, clonenode

I am developing a Ruby on rails project. And in the view file I have some javascript to clone table row on button click. Each table row contains several input text boxes. Now I want to assign the id to a input text box of the newly cloned row dynamically. But I am facing this error:

index:48 Uncaught ReferenceError: item1 is not defined

index is the view name.

My code is:

```
  function insRow()
  {
      var x=document.getElementById('POITable');
      var new_row = x.rows[1].cloneNode(true);
      new_row.style.visibility = "visible";
      var len = x.rows.length;

      new_row_itembox=new_row.cells[0].getElementsByTagName("input");
      new_row_itembox.id=<%= ("item"+@counter.to_s) %>;    //this line causes the error
      //console.log(new_row_itembox);

      var inp1 = new_row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
      inp1.id += len;
      inp1.value = '';
      var inp2 = new_row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
      inp2.id += len;
      inp2.value = '';
      x.appendChild( new_row );

      var sec_last_row=x.rows[x.rows.length-2];
      console.log(x.rows.length);
      console.log(x.rows[x.rows.length-2]);
      sec_last_row.cells[5].innerHTML="<img alt='Icon' src='/assets/minus-icon.png' id='delPOIbutton' onclick='deleteRow(this)'/>";
      sec_last_row.cells[6].innerHTML="";

      var last_row=x.rows[x.rows.length-1]

      last_row.cells[5].innerHTML="<img alt='Icon' src='/assets/add-icon.png' id='addmorePOIbutton' onclick='insRow(this)'/>";
      last_row.cells[6].innerHTML="<img alt='Icon' src='/assets/minus-icon.png' id='delPOIbutton' onclick='deleteRow(this)'/>";
  }
```

The above javascript function is for inserting another row on a button click.

In the code, @counter is a rails variable defined in the corresponding controller action.

If I remove that part and assign the id of the input box statically,it working fine.

My html code is:

```
<body>
<form>
<center>
<div id="POItablediv">
<br/>
<table id="POITable">
    <tr>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>Brand</th>
        <th>UOM</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Remarks</th>
    </tr>

    <tr style="visibility:hidden;">             <!-- This is just a dummy row-->
        <td><input size=25 type="text"/></td>
        <td><input size=25 type="text"/></td>
        <td><input size=25 type="text"/></td>
        <td><input size=25 type="text"/></td>
        <td><input size=25 type="text"/></td>
        <td><img alt="Icon" src="/assets/add-icon.png" id="addmorePOIbutton" onclick="insRow()" /></td>
        <td><img alt="Icon" src="/assets/minus-icon.png" id="delPOIbutton" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><input size=25 type="text"/></td>
        <td><input size=25 type="text"/></td>
        <td><input size=25 type="text"/></td>
        <td><input size=25 type="text"/></td>
        <td><input size=25 type="text"/></td>
        <td><img alt="Icon" src="/assets/add-icon.png" id="addmorePOIbutton" onclick="insRow()" /></td>
        <td><img alt="Icon" src="/assets/minus-icon.png" id="delPOIbutton" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" name="submit_button" onclick="make_hash()">


  </center>
  </form>
  </body>
```

Comment: don't know which is line 48, and there's no `item1` in your code - perhaps you've posted the wrong code

Comment: just look the line:   new_row_itembox.id=<%= ("item"+@counter.to_s) %>;

Comment: I know where it was referenced, just no evidence that it exists

Comment: @counter is set to 1 and it is appending it`s value with the string "item" and it prints item1 in console. Thats it....But the problem is it is printing the desired data but throwing error and its not working.

Comment: oh, I see ... that code would end up `new_row_itembox.id=item1` - you need quotes around that <%= stuff to make it a string

Comment: <@counter=1> is written in the javascript section..I did not mention that line here in my code.

Comment: Thank you @Jaromanda....It is working fine...Thank you very much.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120698/discussion-between-abhradip-and-jaromanda-x).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the line

```
new_row_itembox.id=<%= ("item"+@counter.to_s) %>;
```

to

```
new_row_itembox.id='<%= ("item"+@counter.to_s) %>';
                   ^                             ^
                    -------- added these ---------
```

Comment: Another problem I am facing. <%@counter=@counter+1%> is not working. Its still printing item1....(It should print item2,item3,item4.....) since I am using <%@counter=@counter+1%>

Comment: that would be a server side code issue, which you haven't shown, and I confess I know less than nothing about ruby, regardless if she's on rails or not

Comment: its okk brother :)